# Is it possible to create an embedded react app widget?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs

I want to create a widget that can be embedded onto different WordPress sites. As an example building a mortgage calculator and adding functionality such as creating a downloadable PDF with the inputted information.

Is it possible to do this with react? More specifically using the create-react-app tool.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, shouldn't be difficult. You can start creating a simple shortcode that prints a simple HTML, enqueues React's files and runs your custom JS to build the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of ReactDOM.render is the render target. It can be anywhere on the page.

```
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('widgetTarget'));
```

Comment: Okay, so could I create the JS file and upload it to a CDN then inject into the element parameter? Or possibly use an iFrame to render the React module? Which one would be best?

Comment: Add the container element with an id or other unique query selector to the page where you want to react widget to run. Add supporting widget js. When ReactDOM.render is invoked, it will render your react app (argument 1) inside the target element (argument 2)

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to create react embeddable widgets, but `create-react-app` is not the right tool to do that.

The easiest way to share a compiled js bundle and to use it in a browser is to package it in the UMD format.
However, `create-react-app` [doesn't support it](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/820#issuecomment-250985641). Technically, you can import a bundle from create-react-app as a widget, but it is a pain. Some people do this by [parsing the application manifest](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-embed-a-react-application-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu-18-04), and other by [copying the index html content into the destination page](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-two-easiest-ways-to-share-your-reactjs-project-as-a-widget-971dfef66d98). Most of the time, a widget takes input data and you'll have hard time with these techniques.

I'd suggest you to use another build system that supports UMD out of the box, like [parcel/babel](https://css-tricks.com/using-parcel-as-a-bundler-for-react-applications/) (easiest one), webpack/babel, nwb, etc.
Here are react official recommendations about [compile chains](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#more-flexible-toolchains).

Here is an example `index.js` file you could use to declare a widget :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

window.MyWidget = function(idElement, param1, param2) {
    let config = {param1, param2};
    ReactDOM.render(<App config={config} />, document.getElementById(idElement));
    return this;
}
```

The widget can then be instantiated into the target page :

```
<body>
  <div id="react-widget">

  <script src="http://cdm.com/my-react-widget-bundle.js"></script>
  <!-- if bundled separately, load the css -->
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      new MyWidget("#react-widget", "toto", "tata");
    });
  </script>
  </div>
</body>
```